# pygame.mixer on thread fails with "(pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault"

Tags: python, audio

On the Raspberry Pi, I'm trying to play some sounds using pygame.mixer and am having a problem when playing them on any thread other than the main thread. For example, I have a keypad hooked up and when a key is pressed (for which the detection is threaded) it fires a callback and in that callback it tries to play the sound. But when it tries it, most of the time, fails with:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
```

If I run it on the main thread, it works fine. Is there a reason why separate threads doesn't work or  a way to do it? See code below, the method being called on the thread is audio_handler.playTone()

```
import pygame.mixer as mixer
import glob

class audio_handler:
    def __init__(self):
        mixer.init(channels = 2)
        mixer.set_num_channels(3)
        self._chanTones = mixer.Channel(0)
        self._chanMusic = mixer.Channel(1)
        self._chanRinger = mixer.Channel(2)
        self._dtmfTones = {}
        self._songs = []
        self._musicDir = "/home/pi/music/"

        self.loadDTMF()
        #self.loadSongs()

    def cleanup(self):
        mixer.quit()

    def loadDTMF(self):
        self._dtmfTones["0"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/0.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["1"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/1.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["2"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/2.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["3"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/3.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["4"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/4.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["5"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/5.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["6"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/6.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["7"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/7.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["8"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/8.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["9"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/9.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["*"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/star.ogg")
        self._dtmfTones["#"] = mixer.Sound("./DTMF/pound.ogg")

    def loadSongs(self):
        for file in glob.glob(self._musicDir + "*.ogg"):
            self._songs.append(file)

        print str(len(self._songs)) + " songs loaded."

    def playTone(self, tone):
        if self._dtmfTones.has_key(str(tone)):
            self._dtmfTones[str(tone)].play()
            self._chanTones.set_volume(1.0, 0.0)
            self._chanTones.play(self._dtmfTones[str(tone)])
```

Comment: Does the callback work correctly for a print statement of the button press?

Comment: Yes, it works fine

Comment: Does a dummy class without the pygame mixer elements work?

Comment: yeah... it's definitely pygame that is blowing up.

Comment: Are you passing an instance of the class to the callback or literally the class itself? If the latter it may be trying to play the sound without the init having been run, causing it to explode.

Comment: the audio class, above, is global in the script as is the callback. the callback is passed to the __init__ of the matrix keypad class.

Comment: Are you calling it statically or with instantiated is what I'm trying to get it. Is the callback is to `audio_handler.playTone` or `handler audio_handler; handler.playTone`? In the latter case, the handler has been instantiated, which means `audio_handler.__init__` has been called and the mixer configured (`mixer.init()`). If it's being called statically though `mixier.init()` hasn't happened which could lead to a crash when you try and play. Without the rest of your code it's hard to tell what's going on.